How can I make Cordova InAppBrowser cover the status bar for a true fullscreen experience in Android?
I'm using Cordova's InAppBrowser plugin to display a webpage within my app, and I want the InAppBrowser to cover the entire screen, including the status bar, for a truly fullscreen experience in Android
What I've Tried:
Installed Plugins:
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova-plugin-statusbar
Current Setup:

I hide the status bar before launching the InAppBrowser,
using Statusbar.hide();

I set the following values on my config.xml



I have tried Toggling some of the Inappbrowsesr flags like fullscreen,presentationstyle etc.



The issue is already on github here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/1065

I don't think there is a work around yet
